# Error during mediaproxy installation

Tags: python, gcc, proxy, compilation, media

I am installing mediaproxy on my server debian. Please review the error pasted below. I have also tried installing the dependencies but still this error occurs. Need help on this.

root@server:/usr/local/src/mediaproxy-2.5.2# ./setup.py build running build running build_py running build_ext building 'mediaproxy.interfaces.system._conntrack' extension x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DMODULE_VERSION=2.5.2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c mediaproxy/interfaces/system/_conntrack.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/mediaproxy/interfaces/system/_conntrack.o mediaproxy/interfaces/system/_conntrack.c:12:29: fatal error: libiptc/libiptc.h: No such file or directory #include ^ compilation terminated. error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Thanks. Faisal

Answer (score 0):

Could be a dependency issue. Give this a shot:

sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 python-dev